# How do I show a transient notification overlay using bash?

Tags: macos, bash, notifications

How do I show a transient notification overlay using bash?

I have some custom hotkeys and I want to display a visual confirmation for them.

PS: I do not want to use `hammerspoon` or macOS notifications for this.

Comment: What do you mean with "using bash" and "custom hotkeys"? Are you running some shell scripts which expect manual input and want to show a notification based on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier).

Comment: This doesn't draw an overlay, it shows an OS notification whose nothing is under my control. E.g., I can't choose its location, its duration, or its size.

Comment: Ok, then you can probably have `bash` call an applescript with a loop specifying the duration.  Certainly there's nothing built into `bash` specifically that would interface with the GUI.

Comment: I don't want it to be a bash builtin, I want an easy-to-use library that draws overlays on the screen.